# Selenium - selecting date picker from skyscanner

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I couldn't find a way to automate the date picker using Selenium.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from getpass import getpass
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import requests
import lxml
url = "https://www.skyscanner.ca"
driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)
trip_type_id = "fsc-trip-type-selector-one-way"
trip_type_select = driver.find_element(by="id", value=trip_type_id )
trip_type_select.click()
origin_textbox = driver.find_element(by="id", value="fsc-origin-search" )
origin_value = "Vancouver (Any)"
destin_textbox = driver.find_element(by="id", value="fsc-destination-search")
dest_value = "Dubai (Any)" 
destin_textbox.send_keys(dest_value)
```

I am stuck at the datepicker

```
driver.find_element(by="id", value="depart-fsc-datepicker-button" ).click()
```

opens the datepicker as

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDbRn.png)

Is there a way to automate by passing a specific date ("December 12, 2022") with selenium?.

Comment: the website does not support `December 12, 2012` previous dates and only dates until 12months from now

Comment: sorry, it was a typo. 2022

Comment: Hi @user14290669 can you try my answer, let me know if you have any doubts, also let me know if you need the Return code as well. I have coded it for Depart currently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After analyzing the DOM of the page I found that the calendar class has dropdown for `month_year` and is available in the option tab. The element can be selected either on the basis of text or on the basis class name. I have used text here.

Similarly the date part can be selected by selecting the span on text which is present inside the button.

Here is the code that selects the given date on the page.

```
import re
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

# REPLACE YOUR CHROME PATH HERE
chrome_path = r"C:\Users\hpoddar\Desktop\Tools\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"

s = Service(chrome_path)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
driver.get('https://www.skyscanner.ca')
driver.maximize_window()

date = 'December 12, 2022' # ENTER YOUR DATE HERE

# Extracting day and month_year from the date

m = re.search(r'([A-Za-z]+) (\d{2}), (\d{4})', date)
day, month_year = m.group(2), m.group(1) + " " + m.group(3)

driver.find_element(by="id", value="depart-fsc-datepicker-button" ).click()
click_on_depart_dropdown = driver.find_element(by="id", value="depart-calendar__bpk_calendar_nav_select" )
click_on_depart_dropdown.click()
monthyear = click_on_depart_dropdown.find_element(By.XPATH, f'//option[contains(text(), "{month_year}")]')
monthyear.click()
day_element = click_on_depart_dropdown.find_element(By.XPATH, f'//button[contains(@class, "BpkCalendarDate_bpk-calendar-date__MTdlO")]//span[contains(text(), "{day}")]')
day_element.click()
```

The above example was for `Depart`, similarly it can be done for `Return`.

[image]